# Is there a REST (Graph or otherwise) equivalent of Add-MailboxPermission?

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api

Right now I have a PS script that is checking for mailbox permissions and if they are missing, the permissions are added.

From C#, would like to call the equivalent of:

Get-MailboxPermission

and if needed, add permissions like:

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $email -User $AdminUserName -AccessRights fullAccess -InheritanceType All

even if I can find the equivalent of Add-MailboxPermission that would do it. Cannot seem to find a REST equivalent or even a way with the GraphServiceClient.

I have looked at all of the available MS REST API references that I can find including Outlook, Graph, etc. to no avail. I can add the desired permissions via the web site and PS, but I am trying to keep this solution in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe these are available. You might want to upvote [this](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/5666049-create-an-office-365-api-for-management-of-exchang) in UserVoice, or if it isn't the same, create a new request.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yes, at least it confirms what I thought. Thank you for taking the time to post it. I will look at the UserVoice link