# Similar command/function of Add-MailboxFolderPermission in MS Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Can this PowerShell command

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ayla@contoso.com:\Calendar -User laura@contoso.com -AccessRights Editor
```

being done through the Microsoft Graph API?
And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not a Graph API can add mailbox folder permission, and we can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992766/is-there-a-rest-graph-or-otherwise-equivalent-of-add-mailboxpermission)