# Is there a REST (Graph or otherwise) equivalent of Set-Mailbox and Add-MailboxPermission powershell commands?

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, microsoft365

Basically same question with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992766/is-there-a-rest-graph-or-otherwise-equivalent-of-add-mailboxpermission#) more than 3.5 years ago. Curious if anything has changed? Is it available now?

Was hoping to do below commands via REST:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $userUPN -User $delegateTo -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
Set-Mailbox -Identity $userUPN -Type Shared
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Nope, still Mailbox level operations are not exposed with Microsoft Graph API.
- You can use the same exchange PowerShell commands to perform the
  operations.
- If you wish this to be implemented by Microsoft, [consider filing feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) or upvote the existing one, incase if you found one - so that the respective team can consider it.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I'm trying to find a Graph API counterpart is for me to be able to do this programmatically. My limitation with a PS script is it asks for MFA (multi-factor authentication) which obviously will not work as I'm trying to automate it. Any idea how I can achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. In case of Exchange PowerShell, please have a look at [Exchange Online Powershell Module v2 which supports MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps).

Answer (score 0):

To do this through graph API you need to have a license that has Exchange Online as a service plan, some of these licenses are Microsoft 365 F3, or Business Premium, assign your new user one these licenses on creation and a Mailbox will be created for them